# where to find the user creation code in couchbase couchchat code

Tags: couchbase-lite

I have the couchbase couchchat sample app. I have everything working. I can add a user. I can use the admin port of the sync gateway and see the user.

Where in the code can I see an example of the call to the sync gateway to create the _user entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a sync_gateway side process. It handles processing the results [Ref:](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/blob/0ef9805c5f7aef1f0a8f602636469d6a2883643e/src/github.com/couchbaselabs/sync_gateway/rest/session_api.go)